# how does notation \number work in this example?

Tags: regex

I read from the textbook and learned "\number" refers to the nth group, but I still cannot understand it in the example.

```
import re
m = re.search(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1', 'Cherry tree blooming will begin in in later March, High Park Toronto')
print m.group(0)
print m.group(1)
```

I can sort of understand that it firstly returns "in in ", since "in in" matches what is in the parenthesis (\b\w+). But why it returns "in" for m.group(1)?

Then I modified the code a little bit to delete "\1":

```
import re
m = re.search(r'(\b\w+)\s+', 'Cherry tree blooming will begin in in later March, High Park Toronto')
print m.group(0)
```

It returns "Cherry". I am totally lost...

Could someone please explain these in details? Thanks.

Comment: `\number` is a back-reference, the best here is probably to read some documentation on it. I personally like the documentation on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex `(\b\w+)\s+\1` what you are saying is

> Match a word(\w+) preceded by word boundary(\b) followed by one or many whitespaces(\s+) and followed by same word as captured by (\b\w+).

Since you used capturing group each such pattern is captured in first capturing group and checked for repeated pattern using `\1`. So first occurrence of such pattern is `in in`.

***`m.group(0)`*** contains whole match. Whereas ***`m.group(1)`*** contains first captured group which is **`in`**.

When you remove `\1` your regex becomes `(\b\w+)\s+`. Let's see what it's saying now.

> Match a word(\w+) preceded by word boundary(\b) followed by one or many whitespaces(\s+).

So first occurrence of such pattern is `Cherry`.

***`m.group(0)`*** now has the whole match `Cherry`.

Answer (score 1):

#### (\b\w+)\s+\1

This is because you're matching a word (follow by a space), followed by the same match in group 1. Since `in in` is the first (and only sequence) of the same word in sequence, it matches.

For example, if you have `Cherry tree tree [...]`, your match would be `tree tree`.

#### (\b\w+)\s+

This is simply finding a word followed by a space. Since `Cherry` is the first word, it matches.

#### But why it returns "in" for `m.group(1)`?

With `re.search`, `m.group(0)` holds the whole match, and `m.group(1)` holds the first capture group - which is `in`.